# Windows 10: npm WARN tar ENOENT

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am trying to run an application Android on a Windows 10 machine which I do not use for development. I just want to see if I get different error on the Windows environment that I have been getting on my Mac.

I open the application up using Visual Studio Code and inside the terminal I run `npm install`, but I continue to get `npm WARN tar ENOENT` for a ton of node modules, specifically, one called `\.staging\rxjs-af091c76\`.

I do have `npm` installed, I do have `node` installed. I do have a `package.json` file. I did remove the `package-lock.json` file, but none of this is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some module installer is looking for `tar`, which doesn't exist on your system.

I bet if you were to install a Win32 build of `tar` and put it in the path, your script would continue on... at least to the next error.